'require is not defined' error when I try to run bundle.mjs creaated by webpack
I develop an app with node.js Fastify framework (typescript, ES-modules).In my app, I use Webpack to bundle the app and to compile typescript. The app bundles successfully, but when I try to run the resulting bundle.mjs file, I get the following error:
app/backend/dist$ node bundle.mjs
file:///home/myzader/vc-app/backend/dist/bundle.mjs:599762
module.exports = require("fastify");
^

ReferenceError: require is not defined in ES module scope, you can use import instead
    at Object.fastify (file:///home/myzader/vc-app/backend/dist/bundle.mjs:599762:1)
    at __webpack_require__ (file:///home/myzader/vc-app/backend/dist/bundle.mjs:600056:41)
    at file:///home/myzader/vc-app/backend/dist/bundle.mjs:600138:65
    at file:///home/myzader/vc-app/backend/dist/bundle.mjs:600174:3
    at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:222:25)
    at async ModuleLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:323:24)
    at async loadESM (node:internal/process/esm_loader:28:7)
    at async handleMainPromise (node:internal/modules/run_main:120:12)

Node.js v21.7.3

I have try to adjust the webpack configs' but it did not help:

const config = {
  mode: 'development', 
  devtool: 'source-map',
  entry: './app.ts',
  target: 'node',
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.ts', '.js', '.mjs'], 
  }, 
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'), // Output directory
    filename: 'bundle.mjs', // Output bundle file name
    library: {
      type: 'commonjs2'
    },
    chunkFormat: 'module'  // Explicitly specifying the chunk format as module
  },
  experiments: {
    outputModule: true
  },
  externals: [nodeExternals({
    allowlist: ['canvas'] // Exclude 'canvas' from being bundled
  })],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.ts$/, // Apply this rule to files ending in .ts
        use: 'ts-loader', // Use the ts-loader for all .ts files
        exclude: /node_modules/, // Do not apply to files in node_modules
      },
      {
        test: /\.node$/, // Apply this rule to files ending in .node
        loader: 'node-loader', // Use the node-loader for all .node files
      },
      {
        test: /node_modules\/pino\/.*/, // Target pino library files
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['@babel/preset-env'], // Transpile pino for CommonJS compatibility
          },
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/, // Exclude node_modules and handle other JS files
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader', // Use Babel loader for other code
        },
      },

    ],
  },
  stats: {
    errorDetails: true,   // Display details of errors
    colors: true,         // Output in colored format, useful in console
    modules: true,        // Display modules information
    reasons: true,        // Display the reason about why modules are included
    warnings: true,       // Display warnings
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.ContextReplacementPlugin(
      /awilix/, // The module that includes dynamic requires
      (data) => {
        delete data.dependencies[0].critical; // Remove the critical flag from these dependencies
        return data;
      }
    ),
  ]
};


